# How to set(change) navigator (appname, user agent etc.) in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, dom, com, browser

I'm trying to figure out how to change the info returned by the JavaScript navigator object such as AppName. I can't find any info on where JS actually gets this info from so I have no idea how to fake this info.

Where is this "Microsoft Internet Explorer" stored that navigator.AppName returns?

I use standard webbrowser control (C#). Pls help me, thx.

Answer (score 0):

JS should be getting this from the browser itself.  I don't think you would be able to change it.